# reading huge log files in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have logger file... it will be around 1GB size. 
I want read data from it line by line till a certain keyword "transitioning to different mode" is reached and i want the time stamp for that as well

i tried different codes but its giving my only the log header and few lines from the log file (the file is in txt format)

Below is the code i tried to print the first 100 lines

```
        i =1
    with open(sFile) as fileobject:
        for line in fileobject:
            print line
            i = i + 1
            if i > 100:
                break
```

This prints only the header and few other lines
Could someone please help in fixing this

Thanks

Comment: Ignoring an indentation error and assuming Python 2, your current code should work, although using `enumerate()` would be more pythonic

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. As far as I can tell, all you need to do is rewrite the `if`-statement to `if line.strip() == "transitioning to different mode": break`?

Comment: The problem is that it is always printing the last time of the logger if i put a condition... and when i try to print the first 100 lines it prints only the header and the last line...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

import time

```
start = time.time()
with open(sFile) as fileobject:
    for i, line in enumerate(fileobject):
        if line.strip() == "transitioning to different mode":#or
        #if line.stratswith("transitioning to different mode"): # or
        #if "transitioning to different mode" in line:
            print(i)
            break
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: sorry no. It want the timestamp in the logger for the logged event ""transitioning to different mode". My problem is i am unable to print the data in my logs. When i try to print it ... it gives me only the header and the last line of the logger.

Answer (score -1):

The use of `yield` will be memory efficient for your task while loading huge file:

```
def readfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as fileObject:
        for line in fileObject:
            yield(line)
        yield None # after the end of line
```

and now yield the file lines as following:

```
lines = readfile(filename)
line = line.next():
while line:
    print (line)
```

Comment: 1) Your `while` loop is an infinite loop. 2) I don't see the point of wrapping the file in an iterator. File objects are already iterators. 3) This doesn't even begin to solve the OP's problem. All you've done is reorganize the code from the question. You haven't actually made it do what the OP wants.